# Retrieving URL from MySQL database

Tags: html, mysql

Okay,  so I have a database which holds the following values: Restaurant Name, Address, Town, County, Postcode, Tel, Email, Website and Rating. I have a search box that allows the user to search via Town, County or Postcode and then echo's out those relevant using the attached code.

Problem is, my website URL's when clicked just reload the same page the info is displayed on and not the actual website of the restaurants? I know this is going to be something silly!

Thanks

```html
<td>
  <?php echo $results[ 'RestaurantName']?>
</td>
<br>
<td>
  <?php echo $results[ 'AddressLine1']?>
</td>
<br>
<td>
  <?php echo $results[ 'AddressLine2']?>
</td>
<br>
<td>
  <?php echo $results[ 'Town']?>
</td>
<br>
<td>
  <?php echo $results[ 'County']?>
</td>
<br>
<td>
  <?php echo $results[ 'Postcode']?>
</td>
<br>
<td>
  <?php echo $results[ 'Telephone']?>
</td>
<br>
<td>
  <?php echo $results[ 'Email']?>
</td>
<br>
<td>
  <a href>
    <?php echo $results[ 'Website']?>
  </a>
</td>
<br>
<td>
  <?php echo $results[ 'Rating']?>
</td>
<br>
```

Comment: First, your HTML is invalid. Second, what's the output of all your echo statements? I see one anchor `<a href>` and it wouldn't link anywhere.

Comment: Okay,  what should I change then to correct this?

Comment: You need to remove all the `<br>` from your example, and wrap the table cells in a table row (`<tr></tr>`) in a table (`<table></table>`). Or just get rid of all the table cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your anchor tag's href property some value.

```
<a href="<?php echo $results[ 'Website'] ?>"><?php echo $results[ 'Website']?></a>
```

As it is now, the href property is empty, which some browsers will interpret as pointing to your current page. This is what's causing your page to reload.

Comment: No problem. Just make sure that `$results['Website']` starts with `http://` or `https://`, otherwise, the browser will think you're linking to a page on your site.